# Select auto_increment field value

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to compare the auto increment field value of the current table with a constant value, the method I tried is below query:

```
WHERE (SELECT column_name FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_schema = DATABASE() AND table_name='clients') = '1'
```

It won't show any output, Is there anything wrong with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
WHERE (SELECT AUTO_INCREMENT FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_schema = DATABASE() AND table_name='clients') = <your number>
```

You should try something like above